# Performance-wise, how good is the Guava library?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, big-o, guava

I have been through the [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library and founds lots of good, usable data structures in it.

If anyone else has used it then can you provide feedback on how it performed when used with huge data sets? Basically I am looking for BigO notation for its operations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which operation performance are you specifically looking for?

Comment: The Guava library is large. Which operations are you looking at in particular?

Comment: It'd be great to provide as a chart of new Collections(MultiSet, Multimap, BiMap, Table) operation. Like in java collection [BigO notation](http://simplenotions.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Guava contributor here.

Um, what's there to say?  All hash-based (and enum-based) collections have the single-entry operations in constant time, exactly as you'd expect.  (`HashMultiset`, `LinkedHashMultiset`, `ConcurrentHashMultiset`, `HashBiMap`, `HashBasedTable`, `ImmutableSet`, `ImmutableMap`, `EnumMultiset`, `EnumBiMap`, etc. all fall into that category.)  All tree-based/sorted collections have logarithmic time for their single-entry operations, including `TreeMultiset`, `ImmutableSortedMap`, and `ImmutableSortedSet`.

Among multimaps, well, the documentation basically tells you the `Map` and the value-collection implementations, and you can figure it out from there.  `HashMultimap` is basically a `HashMap` to `HashSet`s, `LinkedHashMultimap` is a `LinkedHashMap` to `LinkedHashSet`s, `ArrayListMultimap` is a `HashMap` to `ArrayList`s, `LinkedListMultimap` is a `LinkedHashMap` to `LinkedList`s (performance-wise, if not technically true), `TreeMultimap` is a `TreeMap` to `TreeSet`s, `ImmutableSetMultimap` is an `ImmutableMap` to `ImmutableSet`s, `ImmutableListMultimap` is an `ImmutableMap` to `ImmutableList`s.

The only thing that might not be self-evident is probably that the `SortedMultiset` implementations provide `subMultiset().size()` operations in `O(log n)` time, which you couldn't do just with a JDK `TreeMap<E, Integer>`.

All the views of collections (we like views a lot) return in constant time and have the asymptotics you'd expect.

Is there anything more specific you were concerned about?

(In general, Guava is basically the core libraries Google uses in production, which I'd like to think is pretty strong evidence that the utilities perform satisfactorily in heavy-duty environments.  Additionally, Guava is constantly being improved, and you get those improvements basically for free.)

Comment: Sumit, see [Immutable collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained#Where?) and [New collection types](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) for tables that explain better which type is backed by what.

Comment: Meh.  I mean...none of this should be _surprising._  Certainly, it's one of Guava's priorities to make sure that there are no surprises about these things...