# Guava Multiset and Multipmap

Tags: list, dictionary, guava, multimap, multiset

I am wondering which in better guava's multiset and multipmap Vs JDK's List and Map
in terms of 
1. time performance and
2. memory consumption

could anyone explain about the time and memory performance of guava?

Comment: They address different needs - why would you compare apples and oranges?

Comment: it would be kind of you if you please explain in details of both

Comment: Aside from anything else, everything you've listed is an *interface* - different implementations can have different performance.

Comment: Agreed with @JonSkeet. You could compare concrete classes performances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance-wise, how good is the Guava library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968958/performance-wise-how-good-is-the-guava-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up multiple things.

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) are 3 of the foundation interfaces for the Java collection library. Guava's [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) and [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), while similar sounding, aren't direct extensions of `Set` and `Map`.

[`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) isn't really a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (it extends [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) directly, actually), in that it allows duplicates, but also doesn't (necessarily) satisfy ordering like [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) (for this, you can have a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), which is a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) implementation). **[Multisets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)** in general are often referred to as **bags**.

[`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) is a map (but not an extension of the `Map` interface) accepting multiple values for the same key.

Also, consider looking at *[Multiset & Multimap: What's the Point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858127/multiset-multimap-whats-the-point)* While this is originally for C++, the accepted answers gives you concrete examples of good use cases where these make senses.

---

So, performance and memory consumption isn't the **primary** concern here. The primary concern is whether or not these are the right data-structure for your use case.

Also, interfaces don't really allow you to make any assumptions on memory consumptions (beside from general assumptions on what you'd expect from a list, set or map type), as they only define an API's contract. What you want to look at are the actual implementations for these interfaces, if you want to compare them.