# Is there a HashMultiSet that garantees both O(1) access speed and iteration ordered by Hashcode values

Tags: java

I'm looking for a **HashMultiSet** (or any other Multiset type), which has:

- **access** time of HashMap based Collection of **O(1).**
- exact same **iteration order** if the same values are **added to the
  MultiSet in a different order.**

I tried using:

- TreeMultiset: It gives order, but [its access is slower than HashMultiSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968958/performance-wise-how-good-is-the-guava-library).
- HashMultiSet: I found a bug for some inputs, example:

  - adding -3, 2.5f => [-3, 2.5f]
  - adding 2.5f, -3 => [2.5f, -3]

  (The corresponding hash code values are also not ordered.)
- ConcurrentHashMultiSet: had same order-problem as HashMultiSet above, and was a little slower.

Comment: Why dont you just build it yourself? A collection that has both a linkedlist and a hashmap and adds its elements to both. Only problem might be the access time for removing a specific item from the linkedlist...

Comment: While thinking about data structures in general is a delightful mental exercise, are you sure that the logarithmic lookup time for a tree-based set really hurts your application? Note that if you can give an upper limit to the maximum number of elements in your set, a tree will also have constant lookup time. And since the logarithm only grows very slowly, that number can be fairly large before your constant becomes unreasonable. For example, if you think that 10 operations are acceptable, you can already place more than 1000 items and more than a million if you can afford 20.

Comment: If the list is intrusive and doubly linked you can do the removal of the item after finding it via the hashmap.

Comment: Well if i dont find any better ill probably have to leave the treemultiset, i was just wondering why how does HashMultiset happens to make different iteration order even than i explicitly overridden the used hashcode methode for it.

Comment: How about ```HashMap<T, Integer>```?  Its key contains elements of multi set and value contains duplicated count of the key.

Comment: @saka1029 The iteration order of a hash map depends on the order you add the keys.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I tried put -3, 2.5 and put 2.5, -3, but map.keySet().iterator() returned same ordered values.

Comment: @saka1029 HashMap's keySet iteration order is simply a walkthrough of the hash table.  There are situations where the order can be based on insertion order.  For example, if your elements have the same hash code then the keySet iteration order will be identical to the insertion order.

Comment: @Pace You are right.